# How to generate a random matrix file on HDFS with spark

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, rdd

I am studying how to use spark.

In scala I hava a piece of code like this:

```
object GeneMatrixFile {

  def main (args: Array[String]) {

  val out = new FileWriter("matrix.txt")
  val order = 20000
  for(i<- 1 to order){
    for(j <- 1 to order){      
     out.write((scala.util.Random.nextDouble()*100).formatted("%3.1f")+"\t")
    }
  out.write("\n")
  }

  println("over")
  out.close()
  }
}
```

Now I want to generate a file like this on hdfs with spark, I don't know how to write the code, anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best starting with the [apache spark guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html).

Spark does have a built in function which could be used to create random RDDs:

```
val matrix: RDD[Vector] = RandomRDDs.uniformVectorRDD(sc, 10, 10)
```